# In postgreSQL, why is \s treated differently from \w?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Here is the example that confuses me:

```
select ' w' ~ '^\s\w$';
```

This results in "false", but seems like it should be true.

```
select ' w' ~ '^\\s\w*$';
```

This results in "true", but:

1. Why does \s need the extra backslash?
2. If it truly does, why does \w not need the extra backslash?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your Postgres version and your setting for [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have tested it the wrong way because I'm getting the opposite results that you got.

```
select ' w' ~ '^\s\w$';
```

Is returning `1` in my case. Which actually makes sense because it is matching the space at the beginning of the text, followed by the letter at the end.

```
select ' w' ~ '^\\s\w*$';
```

Is returning `0` and it makes sense too. Here you're trying to match a backslash at the beginning of the text followed by an `s` and then, by any number of letters, numbers or underscores.

A piece of text that would match your second regex would be: `'\sw'`

Check the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/519).

Answer (score 0):

Some languages use backslash as an escape character. Regexes do that, C-like languages do that, and some rare and odd dialects of SQL do that. [PostgresSQL does it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS). PostgresSQL is translating the backslash escaping to arrive at a string value, and then feeding that string value to the regex parser, which AGAIN translates whatever backslashes survived the first translation -- if any. In your first regex, none did.

For example, in a string literal or a regex, `\n` doesn't mean a backslash followed by a lowercase n. It means a newline. Depending on the language, a backslash followed by a lowercase s will mean either just a lowercase s, or nothing. In PostgresSQL, an invalid escape sequence in a string literal translates as the escaped character: `'\w'` translates to `'w'`. All the regex parser sees there is the `w`. By chance, you used the letter `w` in the string you're matching against. It's not matching that `w` in the lvalue because it's a word character; it's matching it because it's a lowercase `w`. Change it to lowercase `x` and it'll stop matching.

If you want to put a backslash in a string literal, you need to escape it with another backslash: `'\\'`. This is why `\\s` in your second regex worked. Add a second backslash to `\w` if you want to match any word character with that one.

This is a horrible pain. It's why JavaScript, Perl, and other languages have special conventions for regex literals like `/\s\w/`, and why C# programmers use the `@"string literal"` feature to disable backslash escaping in strings they intend to use as regexes.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I hadn't used the letter "w" in my testing which caused some confusion, but I am glad to learn how string literals are parsed in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @user3062144 You're welcome. The way the site works, if you got an answer that answers the question you asked, you're supposed to click the checkmark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The string constants are first parsed and interpreted as strings, including escaped characters. Escaping of unrecognized sequences is handled differently by different parsers, but generally, besides errors, the most common behavior is to ignore the backslash.

In the first example, the right-hand string constant is first being interpreted as `'^sw$'`, where both `\s` and `\w` are not recognized string escape sequences.

In the second example the right hand constant is interpreted as `'^\sw*$'` where `\\s` escapes the `\`

After the strings are interpreted they are then applied as a regular expression, `'^\sw*$'` matching `' w'` where `'^sw$'` does not.